# Rx.net Buffer at absolute time of Scheduler clock

Tags: observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I have an Observable sequence which generates events which have their own timestamp. I am using HistoricalScheduler to advance scheduler clock based on timestamp. Now I need to buffer these events at the absolute time( eg every 5 Min) of the scheduler for instance

S     -> --A-B-C-----D---E--F---

Clock -> 0--------5--------10-------

Result-> ---------A---------D

```
              B       E  

              C
```

I tried using the Generate method and use the enumerator to move the sequence by adding time 5 min to initial value 0-5-10-15 so that a sequence would generate and these events would cause the buffer to close and new to open.

However, the problem is that events are generated not in sync with the scheduler clock so 0-5-10 are generated before scheduler reaching 5min , 10 min.

Please suggest what I can do?

Thanks in advance!
H

Comment: Please show us your code. I'd like to be able run what you're running and see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it out late but i figured out the issue to be a bug in my custom observable sequence which used milliseconds to calculate boundary time however the actual scheduler uses ticks causing it go out of sync.